# Driving MOSFET with 5V PWM for 12V fan speed control

Tags: mosfet, motor, pwm, bjt, driver

I came up with this circuit to control a 12V 6A fan's speed, with a 5V PWM from another circuit. I'm not sure if it's going to work (I'm not very experienced nor knowledgeable in electronics) and I have a few questions:

1. To compensate for Q1's Vce, and turn off Q4 completely and reliably (when Q1 in on and A is low) I added one extra diode in series with Q4's base (total 2). Is this a good idea? Is it necessary, as I thought?
2. Are D4, D5 and D12 necessary in this circuit? (I put them there as part of the [Baker clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_clamp) for each transistor, to charge/discharge the base faster when switching.)
3. Is there anything else that you think is unnecessary/lacking/wrong?

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: Seems like overkill What kind of fan? brush or brushless and what is commutation rate at max RPM and PWM rate?  Show datasheet of fan

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist they are two Delta AFB1212EHE paralleled with each other.

Comment: where did you read the 6A current rating?

Comment: 0.460A   definitely overkill.  Any transistor can do that but you will have aliasing issues with fan and its internal cap may wear out faster than normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbgzBZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Doesn't the inductor damage the MOSFET when it switches off?

Comment: ah yes it would without diode TY

Comment: Thanks, is there a formula for capacitor's value?

Comment: aye , that would be   C1 * f  >= 1  with L1 * f >=5 and DCR< 0.1  but if you go higher in  f  , a faster diode is used  and if you go too slow the LC's get large. and if you don't use a filter  you have to wonder why the fan makes noise.

Comment: As for coil, would 35 turns of 0.75mm wire around a T106-26 toroid core be enough?
(sorry, my first attempt to build an inductor :) as i can't find inductor of this current rating)

Comment: Also wouldn't the inductor still damage the MOSFET, if we disconnect the load, while the circuit is working? doesn't it require it's own snubber? i.e. a current path that doesn't go through the load or MOSFET ...